# How to stop randomised drawings in python from overlapping

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

So, I have written a code that creates snowflakes using turtle. Essentially it asks the user how many snowflakes to generate. It then opens a turtle window and draws the snowflakes in a **random** place, size and colour. The random place is important for this question. Essentially, when it draws the snowflakes, is there a way to stop the snowflakes from being drawn in the (approx.) same area so that they don't overlap?

Normally yes, this would be simple but due to its random nature, I have no clue how to do this.
Here is the code:

```
import time
import sys
import turtle
import random

restart = True

print("This program creates snowflakes. Enjoy!")

while restart == True:
 n = int(input("How many snowflakes do you want?: "))
 screen = turtle.Screen()
 screen.bgcolor("black")

 speedy = turtle.Turtle()
 speedy.speed(0)

 sfcolor = ["yellow","gold","orange","red","violet","magenta","purple","navy","blue","skyblue","cyan","turquoise","lightgreen","green","darkgreen","white","BlueViolet","DeepSkyBlue","snow2","ForestGreen", "gainsboro", "GhostWhite", "goldenrod"]

 def snowflake(size):
   speedy.penup()
   speedy.forward(10 * size)
   speedy.left(45)
   speedy.pendown()
   speedy.color(random.choice(sfcolor))
   for i in range(8):
     branch(size)  
     speedy.left(45)
   
 def branch(size):
   for i in range(3):
     for i in range(3):
       speedy.forward(10.0 * size / 3)
       speedy.back(10.0 * size / 3)
       speedy.right(45)
     speedy.left(90)
     speedy.back(10.0 * size / 3)
     speedy.left(45)
   speedy.right(90)
   speedy.forward(10.0 * size)

 for i in range(n):
   x = random.randint(-375, 375)
   y = random.randint(-375, 375)
   sfsize = random.randint(1, 4)
   speedy.penup()
   speedy.goto(x, y)
   speedy.pendown()
   snowflake(sfsize)
   print(i+1," Snowflake(s)")

 restart = False

 print("Thanks for using the program! You will have the option to resart it shortly.")
 time.sleep(3)

 restart = input("Do you want to run the program again? Yes or No: ")
 restart = restart.upper()

 if restart == "YES":
   turtle.Screen().bye()
   restart = True
   print("Restarting...")

 elif restart == "NO":
   restart = False
   print("Thank you for using the program. Goodbye!")
   time.sleep(3)
   turtle.Screen().bye()
   sys.exit()

 else:
   print("\nError. Program Resetting...")
   turtle.Screen().bye()
   print("This program creates snowflakes. Enjoy!")
   restart = True
```

Comment: A snowflake of size N and position X, Y requires 10 * N space around it. You can simplify this by using a square with center in X,Y. Then you just have to keep track of already drown snowflakes and don't select points closer than the size of a new one.

Comment: Well, can you think of a rule, in terms of where snowflakes were already drawn, that tells you whether a new snowflake would overlap? If you can tell whether a snowflake would overlap if you start drawing it at a given position, can you think of a way to solve the problem? (For example: what happens if you try putting the code to choose a location in a loop, and exit only when the location is satisfactory?)

Comment: "Normally yes, this would be simple but due to its random nature" How would you do it "normally"? Why does the randomness seem to pose a problem?

Comment: Because I am not the greatest coder ever, if the snowflakes had a set radius this would be simple. But becuase of my lack of skill I am not sure how to deal with this issue when the radius is randomised and changes for every snowflake the program creates.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @mx0's suggestion (+1), rather than a square, we define a circle that encompasses the snowflake and for each successful placement, keep a list of existing positions and radii.  We also use the radius to avoid drawing partial snowflakes near the edge of our window:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint, choice

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 480, 320  # small for testing

SF_COLORS = [
    'yellow', 'gold', 'orange', 'red', 'violet',
    'magenta', 'purple', 'navy', 'blue', 'skyblue',
    'cyan', 'turquoise', 'lightgreen', 'green', 'darkgreen',
    'white', 'BlueViolet', 'DeepSkyBlue', 'snow2', 'ForestGreen',
    'gainsboro', 'GhostWhite', 'goldenrod',
]

def snowflake(size):
    radius = 15 * size  # circle roughly encompassing snowflake

    position = randint(radius - WIDTH/2, WIDTH/2 - radius), randint(radius - HEIGHT/2, HEIGHT/2 - radius)
    speedy.goto(position)

    trys = 0

    while any(speedy.distance(other_position) < (radius + other_radius) for other_position, other_radius in snowflakes):
        position = randint(radius - WIDTH/2, WIDTH/2 - radius), randint(radius - HEIGHT/2, HEIGHT/2 - radius)
        speedy.goto(position)

        trys += 1

        if trys > 100:
            return False  # can't fit this snowflake, signal caller to try a different `size`

    snowflakes.append((position, radius))
    speedy.color(choice(SF_COLORS))

    speedy.penup()
    speedy.forward(10 * size)
    speedy.left(45)
    speedy.pendown()

    for _ in range(8):
        branch(size)
        speedy.left(45)

    speedy.penup()

    return True

def branch(size):
    length = 10.0 * size / 3

    for _ in range(3):
        for _ in range(3):
            speedy.forward(length)
            speedy.backward(length)
            speedy.right(45)

        speedy.left(90)
        speedy.backward(length)
        speedy.left(45)

    speedy.right(90)
    speedy.forward(length * 3)

print("This program creates snowflakes. Enjoy!")

n = int(input("How many snowflakes do you want?: "))

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
screen.bgcolor('black')

speedy = Turtle()
speedy.speed('fastest')

snowflakes = []

flakes = 0

while flakes < n:
    sfsize = randint(1, 4)

    if snowflake(sfsize):
        flakes += 1

speedy.hideturtle()
screen.exitonclick()
```

However, fitting snowflakes like this creates an issue.  The user might request more snowflakes than can fit in a given size window.  The code above partially addresses this by returning failure and letting the caller figure out what to do.  Here, we simply try another snowflake size.  Smarter code would reduce the random size range based on failure, and quit trying altogether when a size `1` snowflake fails!

[image]

I've removed the restart logic to simplify my example and because I'm not convinced it works.

Comment: This could certainly work, I will try integrating it with my code, thank you! Will let you know of the results. And don't worry the restart logic works completely fine.